# Keyboard showing half on samsung devices in android app

Tags: java, android, keyboard, samsung-mobile

I have created one android app with one textView. i applied property like inputType : number and maxLenght : 10. this app working fine in all devices except samsung devices.

I have also attached screenshot of device

[image: Samsung Keyboard Problem]

I don't know How to solve this problem. it is related to application or OS specific.

My code is

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            android:background="@drawable/text_box_background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView98"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Please add some code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue..........

I used method inputType : phone and android:digit="012345678" so even in phone pad we can only press the button 012345678 rest all button not getting press.

I also attached the screenshot.
thanks to eveyone

[image: samsung device screen shot]